# Remove Database Server Join with temp tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT l.CKey,
       wl.LKey,
       l.AKey, 
       l.LKey
       FROM table1 l 
       INNER JOIN DatabaseServer.Table2 wl 

        ON l.CKey = wl.CKey 
        WHERE  LKey NOT IN (select LKey from DatabaseServer.Table3 wc 
        where wc.LKey = wl.LKey and wc.AKey = l.AKey)
```

I have this above query and I would like to remove cross database server join with temp tables. Can you please tell me how can I get rid of cross database server joins

Comment: Load the data into a temporary table and use that instead.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you write a query for above query?
It has two database server table joins so do I need two temp tables and how do I load only some rows that I need into temp tables.

Comment: select Lkey into #tempTable from DatabaseServer.Table2. Then adapt your query to use #tempTable instead of DatabaseServer. Ps: how many records does Table2 have?

Comment: @RenatoAfonso A lot, millions. I cannot put everything in #temptable. I need selective data depending upon table1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
into temptable
from DatabaseServer.Table2
WHERE DatabaseServer.Table2.Ckey in (select Ckey from table1)


select *
into temptable2
from DatabaseServer.Table3
WHERE DatabaseServer.Table3.AKey not in (select AKey from table1)


SELECT l.CKey,
       wl.LKey,
       l.AKey, 
       l.LKey
       FROM table1 l 
       INNER JOIN temptable wl 

        ON l.CKey = wl.CKey 
        WHERE  LKey NOT IN (select LKey from temptable2 wc 
        where wc.LKey = wl.LKey and wc.AKey = l.AKey)
```

EDIT: If you need data in temporary tables filtered, then just add WHERE to the SELECT INTO query. The question is how complex the filter will be.

EDIT2: I have added filters that might help with the task of creating temporary tables. Depending on amount of data this will give you, you might want to create indexes on temporary tables before running query itself.

Comment: I have the same query but can I filter data in temporary tables using any keys from table1? Won't that be cross database server join again.
Table 2 and table 3 have large volumes of data and filtering is dependent upon keys from table1

Comment: See the updated query with added WHERE conditions. But don't expect any superfast responses if your CKey and AKey are not selective enough. I can't tell you how better the performance will be, but I hope it will be faster than original solution. Just give it a try and measure.

Comment: If I recall it correctly my colleague had something similar and key killer of performance is join between Table2 and Table3. Even though they are on the same server they are joined on your local server in your original query.

Comment: I can imagine another possible way how to attack this. If you can create view on remote server that will combine both tables, then it might help too, as there will be filter on LKey already applied remotely.

Comment: Adding Where conditions made it worse

Comment: Was it worse as getting data into temporary tables or complete query? And did you try to create indexes on temporary tables? Without them will be your join terribly slow.

Comment: How do I create indexes on fly for temp tables? @marekVitek

Comment: Just like on any other table `create index tmpidx on #temptable (LKey)` This sytnax would require that temptable is #temptable in the query above to make it real temporary table.

Comment: Thanks, I will take it from here

Comment: The index will be enough to create it after SELECT INTO. And also you might try to make load of second temporary table based on filtered data from local and first temporary table. Just combine. I guess you got the idea. Good Luck.